# How can I determine the strength of candlesticks programmatically?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql5, forex, metatrader5

Telling the strength of a candlestick is not straightforward in most cases. How can I combine the length of the upper and lower wicks and the body to wick ratios to arrive at a way of determining the strength of every candlestick type?

Comment: is it a programming question? if you have any problems to get size of a wick or body of a particular candle - np, let us know. If you are asking for an algorithm, you are probably better off addressing this question on a traders' forum

Answer (score 0):

The term "strength of candlestick" is not a clear concept! No single candlestick can indicate any significant concept. Depending on your viewpoint on trading, on your trading strategy, and your interpretation, you can evaluate the market status or candles to make an estimation on the future of the markets. In forex, most of the times our predictions do not work expectedly.